# Embed LaTeX in Graphviz

Tags: python, latex, graphviz

I am creating a graph using python and graphviz.
So my script goes like :

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph()
dot.node('Start')
dot.node('Calculate A')
dot.edge('Start', 'Calculate A')
```

and so on.
I need to write math text in some nodes, let's say, replace 'A' by an integral. How can that be done?
Thanks in advance,
M

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, Graphviz does not support LaTeX.
In theory, you could use Unicode & Graphviz (pseudo) HTML to create what you want, but it would probably be quite challenging.
A (pretty) easy way to combine LaTex and Graphviz would be to create separate image files (svg, png, jpeg, ...) - one per node using your "usual" LaTeX processes and then "including" these files in your Graphviz program using the **image** attribute.